# SP2013 - Can you limit the amount of items in a Site Feed?

Tags: web-part, 2013

Is there a way to limit the amount of items that show up on a Site Feed? We are using our Site Feeds as a sort of conversational wall. It seems to default showing 10 items, but I would really like to change it to show only 5. Is there any way to do this? I didn't see it in the configuration anywhere and there was no view for me to edit.

Comment: I need an answer too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Same here, didn't find anything. Seems to be impossible :S Although you can probably get there with some jquery (I'm not a real hero in that area)

Comment: We are facing the same problem. Have you found any solutions to limit the Site Feed item count? :)

Comment: @Tenttu I have no yet found a solution to this. We are just dealing with it for now. =/

Comment: @Trenton Mak Ok Thank you for your answer! I'll let you know if I find any solutions regarding this issue.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try JQuery or CSS styling.

JQuery: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0b37455a-904e-47b2-9705-e06d8a7029bd/limiting-the-height-of-site-feed-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

CSS: http://josharepoint.com/2014/06/09/branding-tip-custom-style-in-newsfeed-and-site-feed-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013/